# if statement problem within dplyr summarise

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(result = c("no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes"),
                 date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("01/01/1998", "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                                 to = as.Date("06/01/1998", "%d/%m/%Y"), by = "day"),
                 type = c("car", "truck", "bike", "wheel", "tyre", "lorry"))
df
#   result       date  type
# 1     no 1998-01-01   car
# 2     no 1998-01-02 truck
# 3     no 1998-01-03  bike
# 4    yes 1998-01-04 wheel
# 5     no 1998-01-05  tyre
# 6    yes 1998-01-06 lorry
```

My real example is more complicated than this but lets say I want to extract value of `type` for the first occurrence of `result == yes`, the following works:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  summarise(
    type_yes = if (length(first(type[result == "yes"])) == 0)
      NA
    else first(type[result == "yes"])) 
df1
#   type_yes
# 1    wheel
```

And if I want to create a variable if any `result == yes` and want to specifically use another `if statement`, the following works:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  summarise(result = if (any(result == "yes"))
    "yes"
    else "no")
df1
#   result
# 1    yes
```

However, when I combine them in one call, I get the wrong result:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  summarise(result = if (any(result == "yes"))
      "yes"
    else "no",
    
    type_yes = if (length(first(type[result == "yes"])) == 0)
      NA
    else first(type[result == "yes"])) 
df1
#   result type_yes
# 1    yes      car

#when i should be obtaining
#   result type_yes
# 1    yes    wheel
```

Can someone explain what is happening here please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you *overwrite* `result` in the first assignment of your `summarize`, the next assignment sees that all of `result` are now `"yes"`. You can see this by inserting a `browser()` inside your expression and looking at the current data:

```r
df %>% 
  summarise(
    result = if (any(result == "yes")) "yes" else "no",
    type_yes = {browser();if (length(first(type[result == "yes"])) == 0) NA else first(type[result == "yes"]);}
  )
# Called from: mask$eval_all_summarise(quo)
debug at #4: if (length(first(type[result == "yes"])) == 0) NA else first(type[result == 
#     "yes"])
cur_data()
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
#   result date       type 
#   <chr>  <date>     <chr>
# 1 yes    1998-01-01 car  
# 2 yes    1998-01-02 truck
# 3 yes    1998-01-03 bike 
# 4 yes    1998-01-04 wheel
# 5 yes    1998-01-05 tyre 
# 6 yes    1998-01-06 lorry
```

One fix is to *not* replace `result`, instead using a temp variable. You can remove or over-assign later if you still need that.

```r
df %>% 
  summarise(
    res2 = if (any(result == "yes")) "yes" else "no",
    type_yes = if (length(first(type[result == "yes"])) == 0) NA else first(type[result == "yes"])
  )
#   res2 type_yes
# 1  yes    wheel
```

perhaps cleaning up with:

```r
df %>% 
  summarise(
    res2 = if (any(result == "yes")) "yes" else "no",
    type_yes = if (length(first(type[result == "yes"])) == 0) NA else first(type[result == "yes"])
  ) %>%
  rename(result = res2)
```

Or you can change the order of assignments:

```r
df %>% 
  summarise(
    type_yes = if (length(first(type[result == "yes"])) == 0) NA else first(type[result == "yes"]),
    result = if (any(result == "yes")) "yes" else "no"
  )
#   type_yes result
# 1    wheel    yes
```

Comment: Ah, I thought it was only `mutate` that overwrites the previous assignment. I didn't realise that `summarise` in essence, creates a new variable (essentially `mutate`ing) before it collapses the data (I thought it just filtered). The `browser()` helped a lot, cheers! Out of curiosity, what happens internally in the intermediate step to go from the dataset where it has the new variables created with 6 rows to the final collapsed dataset with 1 row - does it `filter` on e.g., `first`, `last` etc. or does it do something else? Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely certain of how that happens, tbh. That's a question for one of the package authors (or somebody with way more familiarity with the internals). The fact that in `mutate` and `summarize`, each expression is immediately available to following expressions (contrasting with `base::transform`, where multiple calls are needed to get new-columns recognized) is a convenient thing to have, but makes cleanup like you just highlighted a bit more confusing. Glad it helped.